# How to make more precise the reading of AnalogPins in Arduino?

Tags: arduino, floating-accuracy

I'm new here so, if I make any mistake, sorry. Well, I'm working with Arduino (Mega2560) to construct an Ammeter and found out a little problem... Arduino Mega measures voltage from 0 to 5V, and the AnalogPins return a 10-bit value according with the reading (that is, 1 bit represents 5/(2^10)=4mV (approximately)). But, in the case of ammeter, I need to use a resistor with small resistance so that my circuit don't get changes. So my objective is read the voltage drop and from V = R.I, calculate the current. But, as the voltage drop is such as slowly, the pin can't read any value.
Eg.: there is a current flowing from 2mA in the region that I would like to measure. With a resistance of 0.3 ohms (the lower value I found here) , would be: V = 2m . 0.3 = 0.6mV. 
As I said, the lower posssible value of reading in analogPins is 4mV. 
Thus, how to improve my precision of reading? For example, instead of 1023 represents only 5V, the same value represents around of 30 or 40mV...
                                    0     -  0 V
                                    1023  -  30/40 mV

Comment: How about getting a 500ms average voltage read?

Comment: How so? I didn't understand.

Comment: First If your max voltage is too small you need to step it up, then create a function that read a large sample (e.g 1000) in about seconds then gets an average from it. This would give you the best result you can get from an analog input.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Arduino hardware and interfaces to that best asked on https://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use 1.1V internal voltage reference, or some more precise external one (This can be archieved by `analogReference`). BTW with such a small currents it would be more convenient to use bigger resistor.

Or, forget about limited functionality of `analogRead` and do it directly. For example 2.56V reference, differential input with 10x or 200x gain (but you'll get range -512 to 511 ->  2.56/512).

Comment: The problem about analogReference is because it change the referente of all pins. My real project is constructing a Multimeter. So if I change the reference, I'll get some problems. I've got great results with the others measures (voltmeter, ohmmeter, etc). There's a way to change the reference for only one pin? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You can change it before the measure and after the measure set the default. But you have to wait some time after each switch to reference gets stabilised. Differential input with gain would be much better aproach, but you can't use analogRead, as it suports single ended inputs only.

Comment: Wow, I get it! Thank very much for your answer, I've not thought about this!!

Answer (score 1):

In below example, `voltage_meter` reads 500 samples in about 1 millisecond and returns the average. I set the reference to `1.1v` for better precision.

```
int battery_pin = A3;

float voltage_meter()
{
    //read battery voltage per %
    long sum = 0;        // sum of samples taken
    float voltage = 0.0; // calculated voltage
    float output = 0.0;  //output value

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        sum += analogRead(battery_pin);
        delayMicroseconds(1000);
    }
    // calculate the voltage
    voltage = sum / (float)500;
    // voltage = (voltage * 5.0) / 1023.0; //for default reference voltage
    voltage = (voltage * 1.1) / 1023.0; //for internal 1.1v reference
    //round value by two precision
    voltage = roundf(voltage * 100) / 100;
    return voltage;
}

void setup()
{
    analogReference(INTERNAL); //set reference voltage to internal
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    Serial.print("Voltage Level: ");
    Serial.print(voltage_meter(), 4);
    Serial.println(" V");
    delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On ATmega based boards (UNO, Nano, Mini, Mega), it takes about 100 microseconds (0.0001 s) to read an analog input, so the maximum reading rate is about 10,000 times a second.

100 Microsecond and no 1000 how the example